# Is there a way to see what a SonicMQ queue subscriber is?

Tags: jms, sonicmq

As I am a total newbie on SonicMQ, I was wondering if there is a way to determine what a SonicMQ queue subscriber is. I mean using a console, log file (by [raising the log level](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/S7560) to Verbose), etc. I can connect to the SonicMQ server and access queue in question using [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home) client, but I don't seem to be able to determine what the queue consumer is. The queue is always empty as messages are delivered as soon as they arrive.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see queue receivers using Sonic Management Console.

- Go to the Manage tab
- Go to your broker and select Connections (you should see a list of connections)
- Select One
- On the lower pan you will see all the sessions
- Under each session you should be able to see the consumer/producer

Hope this helps.

[image: queue receiver on the SMC]

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. If you can, could you attach a screenshot from ManagementConsole, please? I'm asking this as I do not have access to one at this moment. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry Lucas, do you still need the screen shot?

Comment: @j-chan Thanks for the screenshot